# Creating a frictionless caster wheel

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to simulate a robot my team is building using Gazebo. I created a URDF file and I can not get the front caster wheels of my robot to work. I have been following the logic of the code from this [site](https://github.com/qboticslabs/mastering_ros/blob/master/chapter_2_codes/mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg/urdf/diff_wheeled_robot.urdf) but when I try to drive the robot the front wheels are not actually frictionless. I tried changing the wight of the main body that was suggested in another thread but that did not work. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

The Code is located here [link text](https://github.com/benjimen44/iggy_description/blob/master/urdf/test.urdf)

-Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257863/creating-a-frictionless-caster-wheel/) by [Benjimen44](https://answers.ros.org/users/29822/benjimen44/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-23**:
For future questions about Gazebo (robot modelling, physics setup), please ask them on `answers.gazebosim.org`. ROS Answers is about ROS, and we try to stay on topic as much as possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just set mu1 and mu2 values to 0.0

in other words in lines 195, 196, 145, 146 of your [code](https://github.com/benjimen44/iggy_description/blob/master/urdf/test.urdf)

replace this:

```
<mu1 value="1.0"/>
<mu2 value="1.0"/>
```

with this:

```
<mu1 value="0.0"/>
<mu2 value="0.0"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) with karma: 831 on 2017-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1